# Quickly checking if arrays intersect

Tags: ruby

I want to check if two arrays `a` and `b` intersect. Given `a = [3, 21]` and `b = [15, 26530, 21, 3]`, the answer should be `true`. Given
If `a = [3, 21]` and `b = [15, 26530]`, the answer should be `false`.

I tried:

```
a.to_set.intersect?(b.to_set)
```

but this method takes a long time. How can I do it quickly?

Comment: I have no objection to you awarding the checkmark to @Ursus' answer, but why the rush to make a selection? Quick selections can discourage other answers and, imo, are disrespectful to those still working on answers.  There's no rush. In future please consider waiting awhile before applying the greenie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one.

```
(a & b).any?
```

Anyway, I think the set operation should be the fastest one. Problem is you have to convert your arrays and maybe they are big.

Comment: My pleasure Sir ;)

Comment: In 5 minutes I will mark the answer as best :) thank you very much

Comment: `a & b` uses set intersection, so the complexity should be the same as for the OP. `to_set` is written in Ruby while `Array#&` is written in C, so you might have an advantage. Your method can also be much slower with big arrays that intersect right at the beginning though. No need to calculate the whole intersection if all you want to know is if there's a common element.

Comment: Is this one better for you if you want just to know if one element is present in both? `a.any? { |item| b.include?(item) }`?

Comment: @Ursus Which option is better?

Comment: How do your arrays look? Are they big?

Comment: @Ursus rarely may be array A1000 elements. To an average of 100. Array B max 3-5 elements

Comment: If `b` is a `set`, it's `O(m+n)`. If `b` is an array, it's `O(n*m)`.

Comment: I'd just make `a` a set `a = a.to_set` and then `b.any? { |item| a.include?(item) }`.

Comment: @Andiskiy I got curious, so I benchmarked it. `(a & b).any?` outperformed `b.any? {|item| a.include?(item) }` by 3x: https://gist.github.com/jrunning/33e5168306e4b51aa41a6df7458827b2 There might be some combination of array sizes and values for which it's the worse performer, but I couldn't find one. I suggest benchmarking it on your actual data if performance is more than a theoretical concern. (To run my benchmark you'll need the [benchmark-ips](https://github.com/evanphx/benchmark-ips) gem.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
[a-(a-b)].empty?
```

or

```
[b-(b-a)].empty?
```